# Inserting multiple rows using mysql-otp driver for erlang with mysql:query

Tags: mysql, erlang, erlang-otp

I'm using the mysql-otp driver for Erlang. It seems to be working fine but there is no documentation on using it to insert multiple rows into a table.

simple use case for single row insert:

```
ok = mysql:query(Pid, "INSERT INTO mytable (id, bar) VALUES (?, ?)", [1, 42]).
```

But I need to insert multiple values, can I do something like this?

```
  ok = mysql:query(Pid, "INSERT INTO mytable (id, bar) VALUES (?, ?)", [(1, 42),(2, 36), (3,12)]).
```

Documentation states Params = [term()], so probably not, which is a bummer.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly do a combination of [lists:foldl/3](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#foldl-3) and [lists:join/2](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#join-2) on your arguments to create the desired query format:

```
L = [[1, 42],[2, 36], [3,12]],
PreparedList = lists:foldl(fun (Params, Inserts) -> Inserts ++ [io_lib:format("(~p,~p)", Params)]  end, [], L),
%% Then you need to join these with a comma:
Prepared = lists:flatten(lists:join(",", PreparedList)),
%% this will result in "(1,42),(2,36),(3,12)"
```

Now you just need to call the mysql insert with this `Prepared` variable:

```
ok = mysql:query(Pid, "INSERT INTO mytable (id, bar) VALUES ?", [Prepared]).
%% The query will look like: "INSERT INTO mytable (id, bar) VALUES (1,42),(2,36),(3,12)"
```

Comment: Did you try it? Seriously?

Comment: @Hynek-Pichi-Vychodil Yes, otherwise wouldn't have added it as a possible solution. Why what's wrong with this?

Comment: or like this: PreparedList = [io_lib:format("(~p,~p)", XY) ||  XY <- Params]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this driver or mysql can do such kind of things.

I think you should do it likes below

```
 insert_mytable(Data)->
   {ok,Ref} = mysql:prepare(Pid,insert_mytable,"INSERT INTO mytable (id, bar) VALUES (?, ?)"),
   loop_insert(_Pid,Ref,Data).
 loop_insert(_Pid,_Ref,[])-> ok;
 loop_insert(Pid,Ref,[H|T])->
    ok = mysql:execute(Pid,Ref,H),
    loop_insert(Pid,Ref,T).
```

Comment: that's what I'm doing now, but MySQL can easily take many values at a time. INSERT INTO mytable (id, bar) VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6); is perfectly fine.

Comment: @RomanRabinovich Sorry, what I said doesn't very clear. 
I know MySQL can do "bacth insert" by using a simple SQL. 
I mean when using prepared statement, it seems that MySQL can't work with "INSERT INTO mytable (id, bar) VALUES (?, ?)", [(1, 42),(2, 36), (3,12)]".
I think it may work with "INSERT INTO mytable (id, bar) VALUES (?, ?),(?,?),(?,?)...", [1, 42,2, 36, 3,12...]".

Comment: That's an idea!